# "UpdatePipeline" stage in CDK pipeline is cancelled

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am running a CDK pipeline with self-mutation enabled. When "SelfMutate" action runs, and changes to the pipeline are detected - the changes are deployed successfully - pipeline is updated, and the action is shown as "Successful". But the stage "UpdatePipeline"  itself is shown as "Cancelled", so I have to restart the pipeline manually to make it run thru the end.

[image]

Not sure why this is happening now, in my previous experience after self-mutation the pipeline would automatically go back to the "Synth" stage and after that would run thru the end. Any idea what could've changed?

Comment: This is expected behavior - the pipeline should restart automatically. Did you disable restart on update?

Comment: As far as I am aware only `selfMutation` property controls the behavior, I am not setting it, and the default value is `true`. Is there a separate one controlling restart on update?

Comment: @gshpychka I figured it out, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Will post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@gshpychka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10418515/gshpychka) for pointing me to the right direction.

In my scenario I am creating CDK CodePipeline based on regular Pipeline

```
    const rawPipeline = new Pipeline(this, props.stackName!, {
     ...
    });

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      codePipeline: rawPipeline,
      ...
    });
```

I didn't realize that regular pipeline has `restartExecutionOnUpdate` property, which is `false` by default. When I set it to `true`

```
    const rawPipeline = new Pipeline(this, props.stackName!, {
      restartExecutionOnUpdate: true
      ...
    });

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      codePipeline: rawPipeline,
      ...
    });
```

automatic restart worked.